# This guy has asked the same question three times

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

https://serverfault.com/users/44306/mhay - he's asked the same question three times:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/147067/update-dns-reverse-entry-zone-closed
- https://serverfault.com/questions/147057/dns-ptr-entry-table-closed
- https://serverfault.com/questions/145921/how-do-i-add-a-ptr-record-to-a-reverse-lookup-zone

They've all but one been closed as duplicates of eachother. What would you do in this situation? I just know he's going to ask it again.

Answer (score 1):

Flag for moderator attention.
They can merge the question, and notice the user if it is repeated.